# MACOSX - When calling -finishSyncing on an ISyncSessionDriver the app makes repeated calls to the delegate

Tags: macos, delegates, syncservices

I'm using Sync Services in my application. I'm using the normal way of getting the contacts from the address book (using sync services).

I want to prematurely end a sync session if the user decides to do that, therefore, when the user presses the "cancel" button, I make a call to `[driver finishSyncing]`

Attached to the `ISyncSessionDriver` is a delegate which deals with delegate methods typical of a sync session. One of those methods is `- (BOOL)sessionDriver:(ISyncSessionDriver *)sender willFinishSessionAndReturnError:(NSError **)outError`

The problem is that when calling `finishSyncing`, the `sessionDriver:willFinishSessionAndReturnError:` gets repeatedly called, not just once, but hunderds of times. Eventually it will throw an error.

So, how could I fix this, or what better debugging can I do to figure out what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: What error is returned, eventually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instead [- (void)cancelSyncing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/SyncServicesFramework/Classes/ISyncSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ISyncSession/cancelSyncing).

Make sure to release the receiver soon afterward because you cannot continue using a canceled session.

Comment: The problem is that `cancelSyncing` doesn't immediately close the local sync session, which is my goal right now.

Comment: I was thinking that you wanted to finish immediately. But you could wait until it finishes and display a message to the user as so.

Comment: That's true, and that's what I'm doing as a temporary solution right now. However, if the user has hundreds of contacts in their Address Book, the local sync will take minutes before it ends...not really user friendly. I was "hoping" that someone else has had the same problem and knew of a way to solve it.